# How to display response messege as response card in Amazon aws lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have created a simple chatbot with the following flow.

Bot: do you want to buy a book?

Human: yes

Bot: what kind of book are you interested? (Response card)

```
     -drama

      -crime

       -action
```

Human: drama (on click or typing)

Bot: Here is list of available drama movies in store(response card)

```
  - Django

  -  first man

   -true story
```

The last part is problem , I can't figure out how I can achieve that.

Can some one please help me what do I need to do to get what I want?  Similar demo or tutorial Will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to add a response card using your Lambda code because the values are dynamic (available movies).
Here is the example code of adding response card:

```
"dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled or Failed",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText or SSML",
      "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."
    },
   "responseCard": {
      "version": "1",
      "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
      "genericAttachments": [
          {
             "title":"card-title",
             "subTitle":"card-sub-title",
             "imageUrl":"URL of the image to be shown",
             "attachmentLinkUrl":"URL of the attachment to be associated with the card",
             "buttons":[ 
                 {
                    "text":"button-text",
                    "value":"Value sent to server on button click"
                 }
              ]
           } 
       ] 
     }
  }
```

This is an example of adding response card in a fulfimmnet message, you can add this in elicit_slot as well. Play around it and let us know if you have any confusion.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hii sid can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167277/custom-payload-on-amazon-lex-aws-with-lambda?noredirect=1#comment98963572_56167277